# Linux Raw Socket: IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP `Socket operation on non-socket`

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want to read raw ethernet packets from a socket. Those packets come from a multicast stream which I have to join via `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`. Unfortunately, RAW-Sockets don't seem to support joining Multicast-Addresses?

```
struct ip_mreqn mreq;
memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(struct ip_mreqn));

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, multicast_ip, &mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr)) {
    /* Local interface address */
    memcpy(&mreq.imr_address, &cfg->ifaddr.sin_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    mreq.imr_ifindex = cfg->ifindex;

    if(setsockopt(cfg->socket_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(struct ip_mreqn)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
}
```

> Failed to set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`: Socket operation on non-socket

```
cfg->socket_fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

How do I get the full ethernet packet but still join multicast IPs?

Comment: I don't think that joining a ip multicast group works with packet sockets. What sense does that make?

Comment: `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));` also does not work.